# How do I use ClamAV to scan my entire computer?

Tags: clamav

How do I use ClamAV to scan the entire computer? Im on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Ubuntu 16?  So this is a *snap* only system like Ubuntu Core 16.  All desktop, server and *deb* based systems use the *yy.mm* format for releases, there is no Ubuntu 16, but your format implies is one of the specialist *snap* only based releases like Ubuntu Core - is that correct?

Comment: FYI:  I don't see any *snap* available that uses ClamAV, so I don't think you can. As *snaps* run in containerized environments, there isn't the same need as more conventional *yy.mm* based server or desktop environments.

Comment: Why would you want to scan your Ubuntu root? It is not going to find any virusses :)

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 2):

`sudo clamscan -r /`

you should probably `sudo freshclam` to update your signatures before you scan, if you haven't already done so.

Read the man pages `man clamscan` for other options and examples...

Answer (score 0):

Install `clamtk`. It's a GUI for `clamav`.

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install clamtk
```

Start `clamtk`. Initiate your scan from there.

If you can't install `clamtk` using my instructions above, then go to https://gitlab.com/dave_m/clamtk/-/wikis/Home or (for direct download) https://bitbucket.org/davem_/clamtk-gtk3/downloads/clamtk_6.06-1_all.deb and download the installer there. Install it. Start `clamtk`.